# If server time and event time is Equal after message send to user

Tags: php, mysql

1) Script in event time and server time is equal after message send to user

2) Every 2 second page will be refresh.

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); 
   @include("include/db_connection.php");
   //include("user_notification_list.php");
   $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
   $sec = "2";
  ?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    $query= mysql_query("SELECT event_date FROM 
                                tbl_notification_list where main_id =96");
    $row=   mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $event_time=   $row['event_date'].'</br>';          
    $server_time=   date('m-d-y h:iA'); 
    ob_flush();
            flush();
    ECHO $event_time;
    ECHO $server_time;      
    $a= $event_time;// '04-07-14 09:14PM';
    $b= $server_time; // '04-07-14 09:15PM';09:15PM';
    if($a==$b)
    {
        echo 'Message send success fully.';
    }else
    {
        echo'comming sonn event.';
    }
    echo'</br>';
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do it at the MySQL query?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT event_date 
                        FROM tbl_notification_list 
                       WHERE main_id = 96 AND 
                             event_date = NOW()");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
    echo 'Message send success fully.';
}
else
{
    echo'comming sonn event.';
}
```

You could even change it slight so that the time between the query and the event date have time lag to allow the mail to be sent:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT event_date 
                        FROM tbl_notification_list 
                       WHERE main_id = 96 AND 
                             (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, event_date, NOW()) BETWEEN 0 AND 3)");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
    echo 'Message send success fully.';
}
else
{
    echo'comming sonn event.';
}
```

The above would allow a 3 seconds time lag.

Answer (score 0):

I would look towards javascript options to refresh the page every 2 seconds.

> time=setInterval(function(){location.reload();},2000);